# Have kernels list on grub menu

Tags: kernel, grub

How do we have all kernels list on main grub menu, i.e. not in submenu, done automatically by a tool?

Of all 4 kernels only one in main grub menu, please sincerely help.

Comment: The Grub configuration tool should take care of it. It's called `grub-mkconfig`; Red-Hat's distros and derivatives call it `grub2-mkconfig`, and Ubuntu and others have a front-end named `update-grub` (but you can also use `grub-mkconfig`. To help you further, I'd need to know your distro and how you generated the Grub configuration.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.